# Test useState inside useEffect with API call

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm performing the test of my component but I'm not succeeding, the test is not giving setValue and setLoading thus not rendering the data and the test is not passing

Component:

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    street_name: '-',
    street_number: '-',
    city: '-',
    zip_code: '-',
    comment: '-',
  });
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await getAddressById(packageId);
        setValue(response);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

return (
    <>
      <Spinner
        show={loading}
        size="large"
      />
      <TableData data-title="ID">{packageId}</TableData>
      <TableData data-title="Calle">{value.street_name}</TableData>
      <TableData data-title="Número">{value.street_number}</TableData>
      <TableData data-title="Ciudad">{value.city}</TableData>
      <TableData data-title="CP">{value.zip_code}</TableData>
      <TableData data-title="Referencia">{value.comment}</TableData>
    </>
  );
```

test (I'm making the mock of the service and the expected return):

```
  it('should render the component', async () => {

    jest.mock("../../../../../../../services", () => ({
      getAddressById: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
        street_name: 'street_name',
        street_number: 'street_number',
        city: 'city',
        zip_code: 'zip_code',
        comment: 'comment',
      })),
    }));

    const props = {
     packageId: '11111',
    };

    await act(async () => {
      const { container } = await render(<Item {...props} />);
      expect(screen.getByText(props.packageId)).toBeInTheDocument();
      expect(screen.getByText('street_name')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolution (with jest.spyOn instead of jest.mock):

```
  it('should render the component', async () => {
jest.spyOn(services, 'getAddressById').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({
  street_name: 'street_name',
  street_number: 'street_number',
  city: 'city',
  zip_code: 'zip_code',
  comment: 'comment',
}));

await act(async () => {
  const { container } = await render(<Item {...props} />);
});

await waitFor(() => {
  expect(screen.getByText(props.packageId)).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(screen.getByText('street_name')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

});